# Drag and Drop from a collection view to another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a CollectionView of images and I would like to be able to drag and drop each image into a view.

I'm trying to make a 'drag and drop' dress up game - you drag the clothes from the scrollable menu at the bottom and drop them onto the main part of the screen to 'dress' the character

I have been looking online for a long time but haven't found what I am looking for
- Code is old so doesn't work with the newest version of Swift and Xcode
- Code shows how to move images from on CollectionView to another CollectionView

Comment: this could be helpful link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714948/draggable-uiview-swift-3

Comment: Thank you - but the problem is I have a CollectionView which means that certain implementations don't work